# Slow azure site job upload with azure-cli

Tags: node.js, azure, command-line-interface, azure-webjobs

I'm using [azure-cli](https://www.npmjs.org/package/azure-cli) to upload a webjob in our deployment pipeline.

The command I'm using is:

```
$ azure site job upload --job-name $JOB_NAME --job-type triggered --job-file job.zip $WEBSITE
```

The job.zip is 2,2 MB, but the upload command takes 20-30 mins. I'm on a 100/100 network so bandwidth should not be the problem.

Is there anyway to make this upload faster using the azure-cli?

Comment: Add `-v` or `--verbose` parameter to get more information what is happening

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Struggling with the same issue. An upload from Microsft Azure Powershell uses 20 seconds, the same command in Linx takes forever.